# How do i make sure the pictureBox in the method will Load the file only once?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

And not to try to load the same file twice in any case.

```
string lastFile;
private void DisplayLastTakenPhoto()
{
    string mypath = SavePathTextBox.Text;
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(mypath);

    var myFile = directory.EnumerateFiles()
        .Where(f => f.Extension.Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || f.Extension.Equals("raw", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
        .First();

    lastFile = myFile.FullName;
    if (WaitForFile(myFile.FullName) == true)
    {
        LiveViewPicBox.Load(myFile.FullName);
    }
}
```

I store the last loaded file in `lastFile`. But how do I make the check that in case it will think to `Load(LiveViewPicBox.Load(myFile.FullName);` the same file it will not?

Comment: Keep a list of loaded filepaths and check if it exists. Otherwise add it to the list and load the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just add a check to see if `lastFile` is the same file you're attempting to load?

```
if (lastFile != myFile.FullName && WaitForFile(myFile.FullName))
{
    LiveViewPicBox.Load(myFile.FullName);
}
lastFile = myFile.FullName;
```

You may also want to create a bogus value for `lastFile` ahead of time so you don't have to handle the nulls.

```
string lastFile = string.Empty;
```

For what it's worth, you can also hijack one of the properties of the picture box, such as `Tag` to store the last file name.  In this manner, you wouldn't need a local variable, and you would reduce the chance that some other part of the program would reassign the value.